# What is this teardrop-leafed houseplant?

Tags: identification

I recently bought a plant that didn't list its name. I'd like to know what it is, since I've searched online but couldn't find anything.

[image: Plant Picture #1]

[image: Plant Picture #2]

Comment: The leaves alone are probably not enough to identify the plant. You may need to let us know where it was found. If you have seen it flower, a description would be very helpful. Based solely on the leaves, I would wildly guess either *Rudbeckia* or *Echinacea*.

Comment: Yup, Rudbeckia was my first impression...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Eric's comment - it reminds me strongly of [*Rudbeckia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudbeckia), but until it does something else, i.e., flower, its hard to be definite other than to say I'm 99% sure its some kind of herbaceous perennial.

Comment: I think it is a rudbeckia also. I have a variety that looks almost identical.

Answer (score 2):

It's an Echinacea - purple coneflower. E. purpurea is the most commonly planted species of Echinacea.